# multi lines graph in one scale graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

On the y-axis, I can't get the scales of four graphs in one scale. The four figure hold on one on one with its own scale with different order. See the picture carefully on y-axis you get an idea. I want the same scale for four lines.

[image: See this picture]

My code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
plt.plot(z[0]['year'],z[0]['value'],'g',label='India')
plt.plot(z[1]['year'],z[1]['value'],'c',label='Japan')
plt.plot(z[2]['year'],z[2]['value'],'b',label='China')
plt.plot(z[3]['year'],z[3]['value'],'r',label='United States of America')
plt.title('CO2 emission estimates')
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('CO2 emission')
plt.show()
```

z is a list:

```py
[                        year value
 CO2 emission estimates            
 India                   1975   0.4
 India                   1985   0.6
......,
                         year value
 CO2 emission estimates            
 Japan                   1975   7.8
 Japan                   1985   7.6
....,
                         year value
 CO2 emission estimates            
 China                   1975   1.2
 China                   1985   1.9
.....,
                           year value
 CO2 emission estimates              
 United States of America  1975  19.8
 United States of America  1985  18.4
 ......]
```

```py
>>> type(z[2]['value'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: What excatly do you mean by scale? Do you mean the same range? You can specify the limit of y via calling plt.ylim([0,10]). However your plot does not look like it it generated by your code, really

Comment: see the graphs y-axis, there are four graphs placed one on other with same x-axis , if u see the blue line y-scale it is in reverse order  
and i want one  y-scale range from 0-20 having four lines in it  
the graph is generated from the above code only in Jupiter notebook